# Copy Active Cell Comment in Excel into a new word file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

i do not know much about Macros, is it possible someone could help me out. 
I have a simple excel file with names of Clients that have a  lot of comments on each name. is there a fast way other than doing Screenshots or editing the comment, then doing Copy paste to a word file then saving it.

is it possible a VBA Code could Copy my Active cell Comments, then copy them to a new Word Doc, which i can then simply save to my own location.

Thanks

Comment: To answer your question as written, "Yes, it is possible". I don't think that is the answer you are looking for. The likely reason there isn't a posted answer here is because this question is vague and lacks effort on your part. Please ***[edit]*** your question to include more details and what you've tried so far.

Comment: i dont know anything about Vba and dont know where to start, thats why i thought maybe someone could help me out, in cell A1 is a list of names, they have comments on them, my current way to take out comments is to edit the comment copy it open word then paste it into word then save it. i was thinking if someone could help me out

Comment: it would make it much faster for me to do this, but if the code is super complex that must be why no one has answered

Comment: We **can** help you, but we are not a training site or a script writing service. You are asking us to do this for you because you don't know how. This site is not designed for that. It is designed for those who are working on something and get stuck. I will take a look to see if I can come up with something, but no guarantee. OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain how to put this macro into Excel as simply as I can.

To add a macro, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.

This will open the `Macro` window. Then type a name for a new macro and click <kbd>Create</kbd>.

[image]

VBE will open and you can paste the below code in between `Sub` and `End Sub`.

[image]

```
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Open Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Check if Word is open
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear errors
      Err.Clear

    'If Word is not open, then open it
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Focus on Word and create a new document
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

'Copy Excel data and paste to Word
  Selection.Copy
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

EndRoutine:
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

**IMPORTANT** - For this to work properly, you need to enable Microsoft Word Project References. On the VBE window menu go to `Tools > References` then find and select your `Microsoft Word Object Library` (*you will have to scroll down to find it and your version number may be different*).  Click <kbd>OK</kbd>, then `Save` and close the VBE window.

[image]

To use this macro, select the text you want to copy, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>, choose the macro and click <kbd>Run</kbd>. It should open Word and paste the selected text to the new document.

Comment: Thank you Charlie going to give this a try but thanks for taking your time and helping me out appreciate it, have a good day. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question, please select the check mark so others can see this is an accepted answer.

Comment: That worked excellent, its taking the Data from Cell A1 and not the Comment, how do i change this to be the comment from that cell and not the data in the cell. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought your meant the comments were text in a cell, not an actual comment balloon. I'll have to look to see if that can be done.

Comment: thats okay this has helped, i will try and find some VBA code and maybe try see if i can also change the part where it does the copy and paste but, into copy paste comment but VAB is powerful :D

Comment: I found **[this code](http://www.contextures.on.ca/xlcomments03.html)** that copies all comments on a sheet to Word including the address. Looks easily modifiable to your needs. I can update the answer if you want, or add a new one.